# libc init function is not returning

Tags: cortex-m

I'm working on a baremetal application for a Cortex M1 on an FPGA. I'm seeing a HardFault during the __libc_init_array function call during startup of my program.

It seems the problem is, during __libc_init_array, it branches to a function "_init". This _init function, however, does not return and runs off into the weeds until it hits a hardfault. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that the function isn't returning.

I've distilled my program down to the bare minimum with the full source code in the github link below. I also have put the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS I'm using along with the relevant disassembled functions.

I'm using GCC version "gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update" from arm.com. I've also tried the newer "gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major" release and the GCC included with STM32IDE with the same result.

I've compared the compilation flags in STM32CUBEIDE with mine as well, and nothing is jumping out at me, but the elf produced by STM32CUBEIDE is returning from its _init...

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

https://github.com/rockybulwinkle/cortex-m1-example

```
CFLAGS = \
        -mthumb \
        -march=armv6-m \
        -mcpu=cortex-m0 \
        -Wall \
        -Wextra
        -std=c11 \
        -specs=nano.specs \
        -O0 \
        -fdebug-prefix-map=$(REPO_ROOT)= \
        -g \
        -ffreestanding \
        -ffunction-sections \
        -fdata-sections
```

```
LDFLAGS = \
        -mthumb \
        -march=armv6-m \
        -mcpu=cortex-m0 \
        -Wl,--print-memory-usage \
        -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT).map \
        -T m1.ld \
        -Wl,--gc-sections \
```

```
00000084 <Reset_Handler>:
/*
 *  This is the code that gets called on processor reset.
 *  To initialize the device, and call the main() routine.
 */
void Reset_Handler(void)
{
      84:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
      86:   b082        sub sp, #8
      88:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
    /* Initialize the data segment */
    uint32_t *pSrc = &_etext;
      8a:   4b13        ldr r3, [pc, #76]   ; (d8 <Reset_Handler+0x54>)
      8c:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
    uint32_t *pDest = &_sdata;
      8e:   4b13        ldr r3, [pc, #76]   ; (dc <Reset_Handler+0x58>)
      90:   603b        str r3, [r7, #0]

    if (pSrc != pDest) {
      92:   687a        ldr r2, [r7, #4]
      94:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
      96:   429a        cmp r2, r3
      98:   d00c        beq.n   b4 <Reset_Handler+0x30>
        for (; pDest < &_edata;) {
      9a:   e007        b.n ac <Reset_Handler+0x28>
            *pDest++ = *pSrc++;
      9c:   687a        ldr r2, [r7, #4]
      9e:   1d13        adds    r3, r2, #4
      a0:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
      a2:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
      a4:   1d19        adds    r1, r3, #4
      a6:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
      a8:   6812        ldr r2, [r2, #0]
      aa:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
        for (; pDest < &_edata;) {
      ac:   683a        ldr r2, [r7, #0]
      ae:   4b0c        ldr r3, [pc, #48]   ; (e0 <Reset_Handler+0x5c>)
      b0:   429a        cmp r2, r3
      b2:   d3f3        bcc.n   9c <Reset_Handler+0x18>
        }
    }

    /* Clear the zero segment */
    for (pDest = &_sbss; pDest < &_ebss;) {
      b4:   4b0b        ldr r3, [pc, #44]   ; (e4 <Reset_Handler+0x60>)
      b6:   603b        str r3, [r7, #0]
      b8:   e004        b.n c4 <Reset_Handler+0x40>
        *pDest++ = 0;
      ba:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
      bc:   1d1a        adds    r2, r3, #4
      be:   603a        str r2, [r7, #0]
      c0:   2200        movs    r2, #0
      c2:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
    for (pDest = &_sbss; pDest < &_ebss;) {
      c4:   683a        ldr r2, [r7, #0]
      c6:   4b08        ldr r3, [pc, #32]   ; (e8 <Reset_Handler+0x64>)
      c8:   429a        cmp r2, r3
      ca:   d3f6        bcc.n   ba <Reset_Handler+0x36>
    }

    /* Run constructors / initializers */
    __libc_init_array();
      cc:   f000 f898   bl  200 <__libc_init_array>

    /* Branch to main function */
    main();
      d0:   f7ff ffb6   bl  40 <main>

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1);
      d4:   e7fe        b.n d4 <Reset_Handler+0x50>
      d6:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
      d8:   00001370    .word   0x00001370
      dc:   2000001c    .word   0x2000001c
      e0:   20000080    .word   0x20000080
      e4:   20000000    .word   0x20000000
      e8:   2000001c    .word   0x2000001c

00000200 <__libc_init_array>:
     200:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
     202:   2600        movs    r6, #0
     204:   4d0c        ldr r5, [pc, #48]   ; (238 <__libc_init_array+0x38>)
     206:   4c0d        ldr r4, [pc, #52]   ; (23c <__libc_init_array+0x3c>)
     208:   1b64        subs    r4, r4, r5
     20a:   10a4        asrs    r4, r4, #2
     20c:   42a6        cmp r6, r4
     20e:   d109        bne.n   224 <__libc_init_array+0x24>
     210:   2600        movs    r6, #0
     212:   f001 f8a9   bl  1368 <_init>
     216:   4d0a        ldr r5, [pc, #40]   ; (240 <__libc_init_array+0x40>)
     218:   4c0a        ldr r4, [pc, #40]   ; (244 <__libc_init_array+0x44>)
     21a:   1b64        subs    r4, r4, r5
     21c:   10a4        asrs    r4, r4, #2
     21e:   42a6        cmp r6, r4
     220:   d105        bne.n   22e <__libc_init_array+0x2e>
     222:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
     224:   00b3        lsls    r3, r6, #2
     226:   58eb        ldr r3, [r5, r3]
     228:   4798        blx r3
     22a:   3601        adds    r6, #1
     22c:   e7ee        b.n 20c <__libc_init_array+0xc>
     22e:   00b3        lsls    r3, r6, #2
     230:   58eb        ldr r3, [r5, r3]
     232:   4798        blx r3
     234:   3601        adds    r6, #1
     236:   e7f2        b.n 21e <__libc_init_array+0x1e>
    ...

Disassembly of section .init:

00001368 <_init>:
    1368:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
    136a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

Disassembly of section .fini:

0000136c <_fini>:
    136c:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
    136e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer while drafting the question. Essentially, I needed to add KEEP directives in my linker script for "init" and "fini".
Before:

```
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _stext = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.*)
        *(.rodata .rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > rom
```

After:

```
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _stext = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        KEEP(*(.init))
        KEEP(*(.fini))
        *(.text .text.*)
        *(.rodata .rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > rom
```